# How to do a Parallax on Android like using MMDrawableController on iOS?

Tags: android, image, background, screen, parallax

I need to do exactly this app, but the Android version, and I'm with trouble to do the parallax screen change, is there any solution close to this transition?

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Q1JyRmCUu4&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Do you have any code so far?

Comment: Actually just this sample that I'm using as a base.
https://github.com/MatthieuLJ/ViewPagerParallax